# Sendind a ctrl+c keypress takes 0.5 seconds to run. How to speed up?

Tags: python, python-3.x

What I'm doing here is emptying the clipboard and then sending a ctrl+c keypress to copy and return the new copied text.

```
def clipboard_manage():
    start_time = time.time()
    clipboard = '' # empty the string
    #ctrl c
    #keyboard.press_and_release('ctrl+c')
    pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl','c')
    #get clipboard content
    try:
        clipboard = Tk().clipboard_get()
    except:
        clipboard = None
    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
    return clipboard
```

Why does this take 0.5 each run? It's not a pc issue i think (ryzen 2600 cpu). Can i do this faster?

Output:

```
--- 0.5174756050109863 seconds ---
--- 0.5515012741088867 seconds ---
--- 0.5044586658477783 seconds ---
--- 0.5024566650390625 seconds ---
```

Comment: Don't use a bare `except`. Use `except KeyboardInterrupt`. Also, you get the start time at the beginning of the function. Do you want to measure the entire run of the function?

Comment: Call `Tk()` once and reuse the same object

Comment: I imagine a lot of that time is spent initializing the `Tk()` object.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (initializing `Tk()` takes a long time):

```
tk = Tk()
def clipboard_manage():
    start_time = time.time()
    clipboard = '' # empty the string
    #ctrl c
    #keyboard.press_and_release('ctrl+c')
    pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl','c')
    #get clipboard content
    try:
        clipboard = tk.clipboard_get()
    except Exception:
        clipboard = None
    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
    return clipboard
```

Comment: Better to specify exception you want to handle.

Comment: @Olvin true, but I have no idea what exception they want to handle, therefore I cannot specify it.

Comment: This sped up the process and it's currently at 0.3 seconds which is a progress but still seems kind of slow.

Comment: @SethPeace, you can use `Exception` to handle all.

Comment: @olvin fixed it!